# Filling 2D Array with DIV-Container and display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

i want to program a 4x4 Game and need to create 2D Array to store Div-Containers within. My current Code is this:

```
$(function(){
var columns = 6;
var rows = 6;
var f = [];
var $square = $('<div class="squares"></div>');

for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    f[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        f[i][j] = $square;
    }
}
console.log(f);
    $('.board').appendTo(f);
});
```

In the Console i see the Array is created correct. But i cant display it. It only shows something like:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
Object],[object Object][object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object][object Object],[object 
Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object 
Object],[object Object][object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object][object Object],[object 
Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

What is the correct Method to show the generated DIV's corretly?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd want to store only the raw data in your array and then have a **render** function that reads the array and renders the objects (in your case seemingly squares)

From your example you'll have to print the objects in a loop since you're not telling the browser to print the objects but rather the array itself.

Try this:

```
for(i=0;i<f.length;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<f[i].length;j++)
    {
        $('.board').appendTo(f[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to append those `.squares`s into `.board`?

If so, I think you'll need `append`. Not `appendTo`. Also, you cannot append an array to an element via jQuery. Try `$()`:

```js
var columns = 6;
var rows = 6;

var $columns = $();

for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    var $row = $();
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        $row = $row.add('<div class="squares">' + i + ',' + j + '</div>');
    }
    $columns = $columns.add($row);
}

$('.board').append($columns);
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/shuding/1bd5bvz5/

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted to do :) Thank you very much.